# Refreshing vue-router view after ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a vue router with two components,a list and a detail view, with a link back to the list view. On the same page I have a list of the same data that is shown in the list-view component.

The data is fetched via ajax, and as such is not ready when the router-view is drawn. When the data is ready however, the non-router list is updated, but the router view is not.

*How do I communicate to the router view that it should redraw with new data?*

If I click on an item in the non-router list, the router-view changes to the details component as expected, and if I then click the "show list" it changes back to the list-component, but this time it is populated with the right data.

I have created a js-fiddle that contains the relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/pengman/jkwvphf9/2/
(It fakes the ajax by using setTimeout, but the effect is the same)

Html code:

```
<div id="app">
Router-view:
  <router-view class="view"></router-view>
  <br>
  Unrouted list: 
  <div class="list-group">
    <router-link v-for="plante in planter" class="list-group-item" :to="{ name: 'plante', params: { nummer: plante.Nummer }}">{{ plante.Navn }} | </router-link>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="plante-listing-template">

        <ul>
            <li v-for="plante in planter">
                {{ plante.Navn }} <router-link :to="{ name: 'plante', params: { nummer: plante.Nummer }}">Vis</router-link>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </template>

    <template id="plante-detail-template">
        <div>
            plante detail template:
            <h3>{{ plante.Navn }}</h3>
            <router-link to="/">Show List</router-link>
        </div>
        <br>
    </template>
```

Javascript code:

```
var PlanteListing = {
  template: '#plante-listing-template',

  data: function () {
    return {
      planter: this.$parent.planter
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route'(to, from) {
      // vi skal opdatere data, saa vi skal beregne igen 
      this.planter = this.$parent.planter;
    },
    'dataloaded'() {
      this.planter = this.$parent.planter;
    }
  }
};  

var PlanteDetail = {
  template: '#plante-detail-template',
  data: function () {
    var parent = this.$parent;
    var nummerFromRoute = this.$route.params.nummer;
    //console.log(nummerFromRoute);
    var filtered = this.$parent.planter.filter(function (item) {
      return (item.Nummer == nummerFromRoute) ? item : false;
    });

    return {
      plante: filtered[0]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route'(to, from) {
      // vi skal opdatere data, saa vi skal beregne igen 
      var nummerFromRoute = this.$route.params.nummer;

      var filtered = this.$parent.planter.filter(function (item) {
        return (item.Nummer == nummerFromRoute) ? item : false;
      });
      this.plante = filtered[0];
    },
  }
};

var router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: window.location.href,
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: PlanteListing },
    { name: 'plante', path: '/:nummer', component: PlanteDetail }
  ]
});

var app = new Vue({
  router,
  data: {
    planter: []
  },
  components: { PlanteListing: PlanteListing },
  methods: {
    getJson: function () {
      var self = this;
            /* Real code:
      $.getJSON("content/planter.json", function (param) {
        this.planter = param;
      }.bind(this));
      */
      /* Simulation code: */ 
      setTimeout(function(){self.planter = [  {    "Nummer": "0",    "Navn": "Bertha Winters"  },  {    "Nummer": "1",    "Navn": "Jeannie Small"  },  {    "Nummer": "2",    "Navn": "Mckay Joyner"  },  {    "Nummer": "3",    "Navn": "Janelle Banks"  },  {    "Nummer": "4",    "Navn": "Bray Moran"  },  {    "Nummer": "5",    "Navn": "Hooper Schwartz"  }]; console.log('data loaded')}, 500);
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.getJson();
  }
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you do not want to have a component reach out of itself to get data (as you are doing with `this.$parent.planter`). Instead, you want to pass it props. To that end, I've modified your code a bit.

The first thing is I upgraded your `vue-router` to the latest version. This allows you to use the `props` argument on routes.

```
var router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'hash',
  base: window.location.href,
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: PlanteListing },
    { name: 'plante', path: '/:nummer', component: PlanteDetail, props: true }
  ]
});
```

Secondly, you are using `planter` in all your routes, so I have provided it as a property on the `router-view`.

```
<router-view class="view" :planter="planter"></router-view>
```

This allows us to clean up your component routes and add the data they need as props.

```
var PlanteListing = {
  template: '#plante-listing-template',
  props:["planter"]
};  

var PlanteDetail = {
  template: '#plante-detail-template',
  props:["planter", "nummer"],
  data: function () {
    var filtered = this.planter.filter(item => item.Nummer == this.nummer);
    return {
      plante: filtered[0]
    }
  }
};
```

There is no need to *tell* the router to redraw; because the data are props, Vue just takes care of that for us.

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkwvphf9/3/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works, but I discovered it fails if I link direktly to page. If I link to a page that would cause the detail view to be show from the start it fails because plante is undefined. I can fix this by adding a v-if, but how do I then update the component when data is ready ?
I don't know how to demonstrate this with a fiddle since it involves the get parameters, but I can try if this makes no sense

Comment: @Pengman you could use a navigation guard to prevent the route from loading until your data is available. https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: I ended up using a watch on the prop to find out if the data has been fetched